# $Z(P_1P_2)=Z(P_1)\cup Z(P_2)$ where $Z(P)$ is a vanishing set of $P\subset k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

Let $k$ be any field. If $P_1,P_2\subset k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ are subsets of polynomials, then I want to show that
$$Z(P_1P_2)=Z(P_1)\cup Z(P_2)$$
where $Z(P)$ is a vanishing set of $P\subset k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ i.e.
$$Z(P)=\{a\in\mathbb{A}^n:f(a)=0\text{ for all }f\in P\}$$
and $P_1P_2=\{fg:f\in P_1,g\in P_2\}$.
I want to check that my proof is correct.

Proof: The inclusion $Z(P_1)\cup Z(P_2)\subseteq Z(P_1P_2)$ is obvious since if $a\in Z(P_1)\cup Z(P_2)$ then $a\in Z(P_1)$ or $a\in Z(P_2)$. Assume that $a\in Z(P_1)$, then $f(a)=0$ for all $f\in P_1$ which gives that $(fg)(a)=0$ for all $f\in P_1$ and $g\in P_2$ i.e. $a\in Z(P_1P_2)$.

The second inclusion $Z(P_1P_2)\subseteq Z(P_1)\cup Z(P_2)$ can be proved using a contrapositive proof. But, I want to check the my direct proof is correct. If $a\in Z(P_1P_2)$, then $(fg)(a)=0$ for all $f\in P_1$ and $g\in P_2$. If we can find $g\in P_2$ s.t. $g(a)\neq0$, then we can see that $a\in Z(P_1$ as $f(a)g(a)=(fg)(a)=0$ forces $f(a)=0$ for all $f\in Z(P_1)$. If we cannot find such $g\in P_2$, then it means that $g(a)=0$ for all $g\in S_2$ i.e. $a\in Z(P_2)$.

Comment: You have left out many details of your setup: are $P_i$ arbitrary subsets of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, or are they ideals (or prime ideals)? When you write "vanishing set",  do you mean as points of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ or as points of $k^n$ with the Zariski topology?

Comment: @KReiser, thank you for you comment. I added some details. I want to show that statement when $P$ is just some subset of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Also, I think about it as $k^n$ with Zariski topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is fine. I would draw attention to/you should be aware of the fact you have used a special property where you have said "$f(a)g(a)=(fg)(a)=0$ forces $f(a)=0$", that is, that $f(a)g(a)$ lies in a field and thus an integral domain. This is what guarantees the same fact to still hold when we generalise to the prime spectrum....

Comment: What do you mean by prime spectrum? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: As alluded to in the comment beneath your question, in modern algebraic geometry we often consider a more sophisticated/elaborate object than simply the points of $k^n$ as being the "space of points" we are studying the geometry of. You I hope have seen that if our field $k$ is algebraically closed, then points of $k^n$ are in bijection with maximal ideals of the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\ldots,k_n]$, and that evaluating a polynomial at a point is the same as finding the residue class of that polynomial when you quotient by the maximal ideal corresponding to that point. The general theory ---->

Comment: extends this to include all _prime_ ideals - that is, it says that our "space of points" should have a point for every prime ideal of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. This is the prime spectrum.

Comment: Then "the value that a polynomial takes when evaluated at a point" is thought of, in exactly the same way, as being "the residue class of that polynomial, in the quotient by the 'point' in question" (i.e., the quotient by the prime ideal that 'is' the point we're dealing with). As the quotient by a prime ideal is an integral domain, your reasoning as above still works in the more general setting.